# new() usage in methods for C#

Tags: c#

What exactly does it mean when assigning `new()` to a property?
I found some examples of seeing `new` usage in method calls but not like the below.

`public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; } = new();`

Comment: it's a shortcut for `new ObservableCollection<Customer>()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning the new() to a method"? Which *method* do you think is involved here?

Comment: That's a property, not a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [target-typed `new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new), essentially it will create an object of whatever the left of the operand is.

In the case of [auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties), it will assign a new instance of the type of that property, to the property.

So if we strip away all of the syntactic sugar, what you've essentially got is:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
{
    get
    {
        return _customers;
    }
}
```

Incidentally, you can use a target-typed `new` almost anywhere there's a well-known type, not just on auto-properties.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [target-typed `new` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) (introduced in C# 9) and is equivalent to:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
```

So the `Customers` is [an auto implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) which initialized to a newly created instance of `ObservableCollection<Customer>`.